This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found
Cree un nuevo proyecto de angular y me sale este error en el archivo app.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'trabajo-web';
}

This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.ts(2354)
Por que me sale error en el archivo app.component.ts al crear un nuevo proyecto de Angular

Asegúrate de que la versión de TS de tu entorno y tu proyecto son la misma o en la configuración de vsc indícale que use la versión del proyecto, no la suya. Puedes indicárselo pulsando F1 y en la consolita escribes TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version...

@Benito-B cuando doy click en TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version... solo me aparece una version para escoger y es la de VSC, no me aparece para seleccionar la del proyecto

Eliminando node_modules y package-lock.json e instalando otra vez (npm i) debería de poder resolver el problema.

Segui esta respuesta en una pregunta y ya no sale error:
"This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found" with ES2015 modules
Pero alguien puede decirme por favor si haber hecho ese cambio en el archivo tsconfig.json afectara otras funciones de mi aplicacion?

Esto no es una respuesta, estás haciendo otra pregunta. SO no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y RESPUESTAS. Por favor cíñete a la dinámica del sitio. Puedes editar la pregunta para añadir información, cambiarla (mientras no tenga respuestas) o directamente abrir una nueva si tienes otro problema diferente. Por otro lado, estás haciendo una pregunta que se soluciona mirando la documentación! En resumen, poner eso a false significará que el transpilador añada el código que necesita en cada clase en vez de importar la función.
